# In my jQuery why indexOf does not find key from my array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, indexof

I've been trying to get it work but nothing seems to help.

So I have two images both in pictures array.
What I want to do is that when you click previous picture next one appears.
I'm pretty sure the problem is with that `indexOf` because it returns -1 every time.

If I replace line:

`pictures[listIndex+1].show("drop", {direction: "up"}, 1000);` <---Does not work.

with line:

`pictures[1].show("drop", {direction: "up"}, 1000);` <---It works but that is not very useful.

I hope you understood what my problem is and sorry for my bad English. I'd really appreciate your help.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var pictures = [$("#link"), $("#italy1")];
    pictures[1].hide();
    $("#link").click(function(){
        var listIndex = pictures.indexOf($(this));
        pictures[listIndex+1].show("drop", {direction: "up"}, 1000);
    });
    $("#italy1").click(function(){
        $(this).hide("drop", {direction: "up"}, 1000);
});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are wrapping the elements in jQuery object. Even if two jQuery objects contain the same elements, they are still two separate objects, so the `indexOf` method can't find one by looking for the other.

Put the elements themselves in the array:

```
var pictures = [$("#link").get(0), $("#italy1").get(0)];
```

Now you can use an element reference to find the element in the array. Use the `$.inArray` method, as that also works in browsers that doesn't have the `Array.indexOf` method:

```
var listIndex = $.inArray(this, pictures);
```

Of course, when you get the element from the array, you need to wrap it in a jQuery object to use jQuery methods on it:

```
$(pictures[listIndex+1]).show("drop", {direction: "up"}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply. It works now just the way I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [jQuery.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the next `$("#link")`, you can always use **`$(this).next("#link")`**.

Answer (score 0):

In support of Guffa, something like this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/atombob/JSsuZ/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var pictures = [$("#link").get(0), $("#italy1").get(0)];

    $(pictures[1]).hide();

    $("#link").on('click', function(){
        var listIndex = $.inArray(this, pictures);
        $(pictures[listIndex+1]).show("drop", {direction: "up"}, 1000);
    });

    $("#italy1").on('click', function(){
        $(this).hide("drop", {direction: "up"}, 1000);
    });
});
```